# Sacar los mayores números pares de una lista dentro de otra

Tags: python, bucles

Tengo la lista `lis1 = [[4,3,5],[3,5,8],[4,5,6]]` y quiero sacarle los mayores números (mayores a 4) pares a todos los números en el total de la lista con el siguiente codigo:

```
def pares_mayores(lis3):  
    seleccionados = []
    for numero in lis3:
        if numero % 2 == 0 and numero >= 4:
            seleccionados.append(numero)
    return seleccionados
print ('Los números de la lista pares y mayores/iguales a 4 son:', seleccionados)
```

Pero solo me devuelve la suma de las listas que están dentro de la lista, ¡ayuda!

Comment: Lo que quieres es devolver la misma lista pero con número mates a 4 pares, es decir, un lista de lista. Cierto? Si el parámetro que recibe `lis3` es una lista de la lista, entonces, debes agregar el resultado a una lista superior. De esta forma tienes la lista de listas de números seleccionados.

Answer (score 1):

El problema como te han comentado, es que tienes una lista de listas. Ahora con ese `for` estás recorriendo la lista "principal" y por lo tanto tu variable `numero` contiene las "sublistas" `[4,3,5], [3,5,8] y [4,5,6]` y no los valores de la lista que tú necesitas.

Básicamente, siguiendo la estructura de tu código te falta un bucle que recorra número,

```
def pares_mayores(lis3):  
    seleccionados = []
    for numero in lis3:
      for n in numero:
          if n % 2 == 0 and n >= 4:
              seleccionados.append(n)
    return seleccionados


lis1 = [[4,3,5],[3,5,8],[4,5,6], [2,6,2]]
seleccionados = pares_mayores(lis1)
print ('Los números de la lista pares y mayores/iguales a 4 son:', seleccionados)
```

He añadido una lista más con números pares inferiores a 4 para ver que efectivamente cumple las dos condiciones.

Un saludo!